Geometry Nodes Simulation: Create a simple explosion
I would like to know how to create a simple basic explosion effect in Geometry Nodes using the simulation area.
Example: I press play and all instances move away along the normal directions of the emitter surface.
I tried this in version 4.2 but have no idea how to do it. All instances rotate during the animation, but I don't know how to also move them away from the surface.
Thank you.
Here's my progress so far:



I figured it out, and I think this works for me as a starting point. See my example below.
If you have another idea for a simpler or more elegant way, please post it here.

